# Android jQuery fadeIn weird behavior

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, cordova

I'm developing a phonegap app for iphone and android.

I have a black overlay with a loading message that appears when the user clicks on a button.

Everything is fine on ios, but on android, the fadeIn() function only displays parts of the overlay. Like, really, parts. Sometimes just the bottom, sometimes the bottom and the top right corner... Really weird.

Although if I use .show() instead, everything goes right.

Have you ever seen something like this ? (terrible quality but you can see the overlay on the bottom half, and a semi-transparent piece of overlay on the top right corner.)

[image]

What's wrong with the .fadeIn() function on android ?

(Here is the css if you need it)

```
.black-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120%;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    display: none;
    z-index: 99999;
    top:0;
}
```

And the beginning of the HTML code :

```
<body class="side">
        <div class="black-overlay row-fluid"> //overlay
            <div class="span12 loading-splash">
                <div class="span12"><span>Chargement...</span></div>
                <div class="span12 span-no-margin"><img src="img/ajax-loader_black.gif" alt=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="app container-fluid event-creation"> //Rest of the app...
```

Comment: not sure how much it'll help, but any chance you can post a screenshot?

Comment: @NirvanaTikku Not sure if I can screenshot my android app !

Comment: @NirvanaTikku So I took a photo of my phone :D

Comment: Press (and hold) power & home to take a screenshot.

Comment: This .black-overlay element is directly body child?

Comment: @Scoup Yes, adding the beginning of the HTML code to my post.

Comment: Thats strange, I use sencha to make some android apps with a loader like yours and I never saw something like that. Try to add "left: 0;" and "height:100%". Is the only diference about my code.

Comment: @Scoup I tried that but it didn't make it better. It made the overlay stop even higher, letting a big blank area on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some CSS that I use for background overlays.

```
.ajax-loader-background
{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#30000000,endColorstr=#30000000);
    zoom: 1; /* Force hasLayout in IE. */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;

    z-index: 99999;
}
```

I'm not sure why you get a different result with `.fadeIn`, except that jQuery might need to know the width/height of the element, and if it's not visible it has zero width/height.

I've noticed slight differences between `width: 100%` and `left: 0px; right: 0px`. Same with `height: 100%`. You're also setting the height to `120%` which I've never seen done with absolute positioning. You should not have to do that for an overlay.

Comment: I know the `height : 120%` is a bit weird, but I had some trouble with the iOS statusbar and I had to find a quick fix to cover the entire screen. With `height : 100%` I had a white space at the bottom of my screen.

Comment: Try using `position:fixed` instead if you must cover the entire screen.

Comment: You could also just go `top: -1000px; bottom: -1000px;` if you need to over do it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I used `left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;` and the overlay isn't even showing up anymore. Also when setting an attribute to 0, you shouldn't add `px` afterwards.

Comment: try `show(); hide(); fadeIn();` as a test. You might need to create an absolute parent that has no colored background, and then fadein a child div that uses `100%` for height width. The parent gives jQuery something to use for calculating the size.